# Purpose of [ -n "$PS1" ] in bashrc

Tags: bash, osx, bashrc

What purpose does the `[ -n "$PS1" ]` in `[ -n "$PS1" ] && source ~/.bash_profile;` serve? This line is included in a `.bashrc` of a dotfiles [repo](https://github.com/springload/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/.bashrc#L1).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is checking whether the shell is interactive or not. In this case, only sourcing the `~/.bash_profile` file if the shell is interactive.

See ["Is this Shell Interactive?"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) in the bash manual, which cites that specific idiom. (It also recommends checking whether the shell is interactive by testing whether the `$-` special variable contains the `i` character, which is a better approach to this problem.)

Comment: bash, at least, will [unset PS1 and PS2 if the shell is interactive](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?h=bash-4.4#n648). You can see that for yourself, with `( export PS1='abc$ '; bash -c 'echo "[$PS1]"' )`, which simply prints `[]`. It seems zsh does not do the same, at least from an experiment... In any case, the *intention* of the `[ -n "$PS1" ]` is to check whether the shell is interactive or not.

Comment: That `bash` unsets PS1 when non-interactive (typo in your previous comment) is a bug IMO, PS1 is not a bash-specific variable, it has no business unsetting it. It's the only shell that does that (though `yash` also sets `PS1` to a default value even when non-interactive).

Comment: Since the code in question is in a bash-specific file, this seems like a reasonable answer. Other answers address the more-general case of POSIX specs or other shells.  You’ve answered the “what is the purpose of this?” intention in the Question while appropriately leaving aside the rest. It’s good to know what bash is doing and possibly better ways to accomplish the goal, too.

Comment: I would consider this answer more complete if it suggested a more reliable alternative (say, `[[ $- = *i* ]] && source ~/.bash_profile`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Frankly I don't think there's much wrong with `[ -n "${PS1}" ]`, but I have still updated my answer to highlight that the bash manual also suggests/recommends inspecting `$-` to determine whether the shell is interactive, I hope you find that improves the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that bash unsets `PS1`. That makes does make the code correct. Convoluted and non-portable, but correct.

Answer (score 22):

#### What this does

This is a widespread way of testing whether the shell is interactive. Beware that it only works in bash, it doesn't work with other shells. So it's ok (if silly) for `.bashrc`, but it wouldn't work in `.profile` (which is read by sh, and bash is only one of the possible implementations of sh, and not the most common one).

#### Why it works (in bash only!)

An interactive shell sets the [shell variable `PS1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-PS1) to the default prompt string. So if the shell is interactive, `PS1` is set (unless the user's `.bashrc` has removed it, which can't have happened yet at the top of `.bashrc`, and you could consider that it's a silly thing to do anyway).

The converse is true in bash: non-interactive instances of bash unset `PS1` when they start. Note that this behavior is specific to bash, and is arguably a bug (why would `bash -c '… do stuff with $var…'` not work when `var` is `PS1`?). But all versions of bash up to and including 4.4 (the latest version as I write) do this.

Many systems export `PS1` to the environment. It's a bad idea, because many different shells use `PS1` but with a different syntax (e.g. [bash's prompt escapes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) are completely different from [zsh's prompt escapes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html)). But it's widespread enough that in practice, seeing that `PS1` is set is not a reliable indicator that the shell is interactive. The shell might have inherited `PS1` from the environment.

#### Why it's (mis)used here

`.bashrc` is the file that bash reads at startup when it's interactive. A less well-known fact is that bash also reads `.bashrc` is a login shell and bash's heuristics conclude that this is a remote session (bash checks if its parent is `rshd` or `sshd`). In this second case, it's unlikely that `PS1` would be set in the environment, because no dot file has run yet.

However, the way the code uses this information is counterproductive.

- If the shell is an interactive shell, then this runs `.bash_profile` in that shell. But `.bash_profile` is a login-time script. It might run some programs that are intended to be run only once per session. It might override some environment variables that the user had deliberately set to a different value before running that shell. Running `.bash_profile` in a non-login shell is disruptive.
- If the shell is a non-interactive remote login shell, it won't load `.bash_profile`. But this is the case where loading `.bash_profile` could be useful, because a non-interactive login shell doesn't automatically load `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`.

I think the reason people do this is for users who log in through a GUI (a very common case) and who put their environment variable settings in `.bash_profile` rather than `.profile`. Most GUI login mechanisms invoke `.profile` but not `.bash_profile` (reading `.bash_profile` would require running bash as part of the session startup, instead of sh). With this configuration, when the user opens a terminal, they'll get their environment variables. However, the user will not get their environment variables in GUI applications, which is a very common source of confusion. The solution here is to use `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile` to set environment variables. Adding a bridge between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` creates more problems than it solves.

#### What to do instead

There's a straightforward, portable way of testing whether the current shell is interactive: test whether the option `-i` is enabled.

```
case $- in
  *i*) echo "This shell is interactive";;
  *) echo "This shell is not interactive";;
esac
```

This is useful in `.bashrc` to **read `.profile` only if the shell is non-interactive** — i.e. the opposite of what the code does! Read `.profile` if bash is a (non-interactive) login shell, and don't read it if it's an interactive shell.

```
if [[ $- != *i* && -r ~/.profile ]]; then . ~/.profile; fi
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that a better way to test if a shell is interactive is with `[[ -o interactive ]]` (ksh, bash, zsh) or `case $- in (*i*) ...; esac` (POSIX)

Comment: My bash (version 4.4.12) actually seems to unset `PS1` if not run interactively.  It is easy enough to test: `PS1=cuckoo bash -c '[ -n "${PS1}" ] && echo "PS1=[${PS1}]"'` will not print anything, while `PS1=cuckoo bash -i -c '[ -n "${PS1}" ] && echo "PS1=[${PS1}]"'` prints the value of `$PS1` set in your bash startup files (it will not print the string "cuckoo").

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: POSIX does not require that `$-` contains `i` with an interactive shell.

Comment: The real solution for the final paragraph is to set the variables (or source a common variable-setting script) from your `.xsessionrc` or equivalent.

Comment: @schily, not yet, but [probably in the next version](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1039). AFAIK, all POSIX shells do it. Did you not actually update bosh so it does it as well as per that POSIX enhancement proposal?

Comment: Bosh does this since 2012 to be compatible to ksh. It just was not required by POSIX until the change you mantion becomes effective.

Comment: Frankly, I'd say calling `[ -n "${PS1}" ]` **wrong** is going a bit too far, after all it only breaks when someone is exporting PS1 (which in your answer you say it's a bad idea and even go into the reasons why) and that doesn't affect bash anyways (since it unsets PS1 and PS2 if the shell is non-interactive.) Maybe using a word such as "discouraged" or talking about the "limitations" of the approach would have been better. I don't think it's "wrong" altogether. If anything is **wrong** is exporting PS1, that's for sure! Anyways, thanks for going into the details of this.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger I thought it was wrong because I didn't know that bash unsets `PS1` when running non-interactively. Since bash does this, the code is correct in .bashrc (because this is a bash-specific file). I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this strange concept is a result from the fact that `bash` did not start as a POSIX shell clone but as a `Bourne Shell` clone.

As a result, the POSIX interactive behavior (`$ENV` gets called for interactive shells) has been added later to `bash` and is not widely known.

There is one shell that grants similar behavior. This is `csh` and csh grants that `$prompt` has specific values:

```
$prompt not set          non-interactive shell, test $?prompt.
$prompt set but == ""    .cshrc called by the which(1) command.
$prompt set and != ""    normal interactive shell.
```

But this neither applies to the Bourne Shell nor to POSIX shells.

For a POSIX shell, the only granted method is to put code for interactive shells into the file:

```
$ENV
```

that has a shell specific name. It is e.g.

```
$HOME/.kshrc    for the korn shell
$HOME/.bashrc   for bash
$HOME/.mkshrc   for mksh
$HOME/.shrc     for the POSIX Bourne Shell
```

Other people mentioned the shell flag `-i`, but this is not usable for reliable programming. POSIX neither requires that `set -i` works, nor that `$-` contains an `i` for interactive shells. POSIX just requires that `sh -i` enforces the shell into the interactive mode.

Since the variable `$PS1` can be imported from the environment, it may have a value even in non-interactive mode. The fact that `bash` `unset`s `PS1` in any non-interactive shell is not granted by the standard and not done by any other shell.

So clean programming (even with `bash`) is to put the commands for interactive shells into `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

I am going first to talk of what Debian, and most of the time also Ubuntu sets for bash. And latter touch on other systems.

In the setting of shell start files there is a lot of opinion.
I also have my opinion but I will try to show existing examples of correct settings.
I'll use debuan as it is quite easy to find examples of its files.
And debian is heavily used, so the settings have been well tested,

## What is the goal of checking that PS1 is set?

Only to find out if the shell is interactive.

The [default `/etc/profile` in debian](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017509/772601) and ubuntu (from /usr/share/base-files/profile):

```
if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
    if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
```

The if's read: if interactive (PS1 default set) and it is a bash shell (but not acting as a default `sh`) then change PS1 to a particular new one (not the default one).

The [default `/etc/bash.bashrc` in debian](https://askubuntu.com/a/55555/772601) also contains:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Which is pretty clear in what it does: If interactive don't source (the rest).

However, [in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` is an example](https://askubuntu.com/a/404428/772601) of the correct way to test for an interactive shell (using `$-`):

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

That should show clearly the why of PS1 and one alternative.

## The correct order

The setting you are reporting should be avoided.
The order (from system settings to more specific user settings (for bash)) is `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and finally `~/.bashrc`. That places the most broad effects (and for more shells) in `/etc/profile` (which is owned by root) followed by `/etc/bash.bashrc` (which is also owned by root) but only affects bash. Then come the personal settings in `$HOME`, the first is `~/.profile` for most shells and `~/.bashrc` (almost equivalent to `~/.bash_profile`), specific for bash only.

It is therefore wrong to source `~/.bashrc` in `~/.profile`, it is transforming an specific user setting for bash to a more general that is [affecting more shells](https://askubuntu.com/q/980121/772601). Except if [done in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953085/9110606):

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

It checks that bash is running and only load `.bashrc` if that is the case.

This is an upstream decision coming from Debian. [The rationale is explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/435503/772601).

In fact, the reverse, sourcing `~/.profile` in `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`) is only re-applying general rules that should had been loaded already to a particular use case, and therefore "not that bad" (I am not saying "good"). And I am not saying good because it may cause the sourcing of files to loop. Like when a sub-directory loads a parent, that is a directory loop.

And is in this cross sourcing that the check for interactive shell makes sense. Only when a shell is interactive is `~/.bashrc` loaded, but it in turn may be loading `~/.profile` (or the other way around) and is in this case that checking for an interactive shell could be used.